# How can i flip the Y axis of a normal map in the Blender Render texture tab?

Tags: shaders

I have flipped the Y axis of a normal map to make it compatible with Unreal 4 but when i want to see how it looks in the Blender Render viewport the lighting is inverted. Is there an option to flip it in the viewport?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Invert the Y/green channel with RGB Curves

[image: invert]

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to fix it is to go to UV/Image Editor, select the normal texture, then Image, invert, flip green channel, save the image.